# gmail login failure using python and imaplib

Tags: python, email, gmail-imap

I'm seeking some help logging into a gmail account and downloading some emails using a python script. I'm trying to adapt an approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail), but I'm running into a problem  with step 1, accessing the account via imap.

here is the code I'm starting with:

```
import email
import imaplib

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
rc, resp = m.login('myemailaddress','mypassword')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import email, imaplib
  File "/home/will/wd/email.py", line 14, in <module>
     m.login('myemailaddress','mypassword')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imaplib.py", line 538, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
 imaplib.error: b'[ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 (Failure)'
```

Imap is indeed enabled in gmail settings. I have looked at the instruction on the google support link and questions regarding this error in similar situations, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479240/python-imaplib-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013736/how-can-i-avoid-google-mail-server-asking-me-to-log-in-via-browser), but my situation is different from the first because 
1) it never worked to start with, and
 2) I'm not running it so frequently to get blocked. Its also different from the second example because this is a normal gmail account, not a custom domain with a google apps account. 
Using the https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha to try and allow access doesn't work for me either.

The only thing that allows login to work is to change my google accounts security settings to "allow access for less secure apps".

My question is: how can I fix my code (or my setup more generally) to allow me to login, without relaxing my accounts security settings? Is there some way to meet security requirements using libimap?

Comment: Did you enable IMAP in your Gmail settings?

Comment: I did indeed, I'll edit to say so

Comment: You need to use "less secure setting", or integrate support for googles oauth2 authentication system.

Comment: I ran the same code and it executed without error. I suspect this has something to do with your settings or credentials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid google mail server asking me to log in via browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013736/how-can-i-avoid-google-mail-server-asking-me-to-log-in-via-browser)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to avoid this error without compromising your account's security, use OAuth to authenticate. The protocol is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol), and there is [Python sample code](https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough) that shows the use of XOAUTH2 with imaplib.

Independent of this, you should consider enabling [two-step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) on your account to make it more secure. If you do, you can use an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) to connect to IMAP, which might also avoid the above warning.

Comment: Long overdue acceptance - barely any time to work on this! I can succesfully log in using OAUTH2 via [rauth](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) while still disallowing 'less secure apps'. Haven't worked out the code to actually read the emails using this access method, but the log-in works.

Answer (score 23):

You can try to turn on this: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
This action solved the same problem for me.

Comment: Try to include pertinent details from the links you provide in case the link dies in the future.

Comment: @AlexOls This does work for me. But, I noted in my question that I did this, and specifically asked if there was a way to get imaplib working _without_ changing my account security settings, so I can't mark this as correct.

Comment: This does not work for me if I run my tests using Docker with Ubuntu Linux. But locally it's working. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

With the new gmail´s update, some mail servr or apps get blocked due to the new gmails security settings. To solve this, I went to https://www.google.com/settings/security page and 'enabled' Access for less secure apps.

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly 3 reasons why this error occurs:

1. Internet Connection Issue
2. Incorrect Login Credentials
3. myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps is ***turned off***

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using a text-mode browser (elinks) to verify my login from the remote server. I had already struggled a while, so I had already tried enabling unsafe apps and various other incantations.

After logging in to gmail.com in elinks (using the html-only interface and having a security code sent to my phone) I could use imaplib to access the gmail account. Presumably one must do web-authentication from the same IP one tries to use Python/imaplib from.

It's probably Better™ to use the OAuth protocol, but this way I got my  script running again without rewriting it.