# Unable to login to gmail - imaplib.error - ALERT Please log in via your web browser

Tags: python-2.7, email, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am trying to login to gmail and read the messages from python package. But getting an **Error : [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)**

```
import imaplib
import email

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
m.login("username@gmail.com","password")
m.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"')

result, data = m.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search all email and return uids
if result == 'OK':
    for num in data[0].split():
        result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
    if result == 'OK':
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])    # raw email text including headers
        print('From:' + email_message['From'])

m.close()
m.logout()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413301/gmail-login-failure-using-python-and-imaplib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gmail login failure using python and imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413301/gmail-login-failure-using-python-and-imaplib)

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip : How to use imaplib, without two-step verification ? I don't want to use two-step verification. is there any simple script which shows usage of only with credentials or with Oauth2 ?

Comment: The link is available at the page mentioned in the error messge: "Allowing less secure apps to access your account" => https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 . It should make gmail IMAP behave like classic IMAP.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Got the second way to make it less secure. If at all to use credentials, how do i do that ?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip : Without setting to low security settings, any way to deal with code ?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip : I've enabled "Less Secure for apps". But even then, getting the same error.

Comment: Log once - AFAIR google/gmail may want you to clean "suspicious activity detected" flags.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip resolved it, some settings issue. any code to deal without changing to low security settings ?

Answer (score 7):

It's work for me:

- Turn ON https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
- If still get error then visit https://accounts.google.com/b/4/DisplayUnlockCaptcha (where 4 is your authuser id in list logged in account), and click `Continue`

Comment: It's better if you switch to you App password, see more
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Just turn this ON for your Gmail account - https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps