# How to use Oauth to authenticate gmail in python?

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am trying to login to gmail and read the inbox messages (Subject, content).
I have basic code for that to login and read the messages. But I'm unable to do so. Reason for this is, I will have to use Oauth to authenticate orchange the settings in gmail as "Allow less secure apps to **ON**" (I tried and it's working) as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413301/gmail-login-failure-using-python-and-imaplib?noredirect=1&lq=1). But i don't want to go with second option to change settings. How do i use Oauth/Oauth2 to login to gmail and read the inbox messages, subject and content (Python code) ?

Comment: Google has a pretty good quick start guide for Python.  What have you tried and what's not working?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) which describes OAuth 2.0, when to use it, how to acquire client IDs, and how to use it with the Google APIs Client Library for Python. The [`oauth2client`](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) library is included with the Google APIs Client Library for Python. It handles all steps of the OAuth 2.0 protocol required for making API calls. It is available as a separate [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2client) if you only need an OAuth 2.0 library. The sections below describe important modules, classes, and functions of this library.

Check this [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) for Gmail API.